# Does IBM Watson discovery support documents with ".PPT" format?

Tags: powerpoint, watson-discovery

Are power point presentations supported by IBM Watson discovery? If not what are other possible options ?

Comment: https://ibm-watson.ideas.aha.io/ideas/WDS-I-103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovery does not yet natively support PowerPoint files. Support for additional file types may be added in the future, see this [Watson Idea](https://ibm-watson.ideas.aha.io/ideas/WDS-I-103).

For now, if you can export your PowerPoint presentation to PDF or HTML format, then Discovery will accept the file.

Comment: Thanks for the info Adams !

Answer (score 0):

Discovery just rolled out a new feature in beta called smart document understanding. If you use the tooling and create a new collection, you'll be able to upload PPT along with a bunch of other new file types such as jpeg, tiff, and excel.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/sdu.html#sdu